# Deixar apenas data no datatime, sem a parte das horas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

Olá, tenho um projeto que chama uma `WebApi` que traz os dados do banco de dados, porém um dos campos no banco de dados é do tipo `DateTime` e no meu projeto, declarei como String (posso alterar, não tem problema), o que eu quero é o seguinte: queria que quando traz esse valor, tira a parte das `horas` e deixe apenas a `data`

O campo é: `Cba_dt_abertura`

Como posso fazer uma conversão, ou talvez tirar essa parte, segue imagens:

Como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como devia ser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu projeto:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        Uri BaseAdress = Services.Token.BaseAdress;
        string strToken = Services.Token.strToken;
        List<ContaBancariaModel> ListaContaBancaria;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = BaseAdress;
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strToken);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Application/Json"));
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("/api/ContaBancaria/findAll"))
            {

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string resul = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ListaContaBancaria = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContaBancariaModel>>(resul);
            }
        }
        return View(ListaContaBancaria);
    }
```

Método na WebApi:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("findAll")]
    public HttpResponseMessage findAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var bancos = bdprincipalEntities.Contas_Bancarias.Select(
                    x => new {
                        Cba_codigo = x.Cba_codigo,
                        Cba_numero = x.Cba_numero,
                        Cba_tipo_conta = x.Cba_tipo_conta,
                        Cba_dt_abertura = x.Cba_dt_abertura,
                        Cba_gerente = x.Cba_gerente,
                        Emp_codigo = x.Emp_codigo,
                        Cba_situacao = x.Cba_situacao.Equals("A") ? "ATIVO" : "DESATIVADO"                           
                    }).ToList();
            result.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bancos));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altere o tipo do objeto Cba_dt_abertura de string para DateTime, após isso quando for popular a list coloque o código abaixo.

```
    try
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var bancos = bdprincipalEntities.Contas_Bancarias.Select(
                x => new {
                    Cba_codigo = x.Cba_codigo,
                    Cba_numero = x.Cba_numero,
                    Cba_tipo_conta = x.Cba_tipo_conta,
                    Cba_dt_abertura = x.Cba_dt_abertura.ToShortDateString(), //Coloque esse método
                    Cba_gerente = x.Cba_gerente,
                    Emp_codigo = x.Emp_codigo,
                    Cba_situacao = x.Cba_situacao.Equals("A") ? "ATIVO" : "DESATIVADO"                           
                }).ToList();
        result.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bancos));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Eu não sei se você testou, mas o visual studio diz que DateTime não contém uma definição para 'ToShortDateString'

Comment: Quando eu acrescento o ponto eu apenas posso usar os seguintes métodos:  "Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, GetValueOrDefault e ToString".

Comment: Documentação do método: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: A resposta do João está correta, porém é importante observar que, o método ToShortDateString() é aplicado em propriedades do tipo DateTime. O Jeff não conseguiu encontrar o método provavelmente pelo fato de sua propriedade Cba_dt_abertura ser do tipo string. Jeff, conforme você informou, você pode alterar o tipo de sua propriedade. Modifique para DateTime isso provavelmente lhe permitirá acessar ao método ToShortDateString().

Comment: Como dito pelo @SérgioLopes, o método está disponivel apenas para o tipo DateTime

Comment: Ah sim, não sabia disso, obrigado pelas resposta

Comment: {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."} recebo este erro ao usar esse método

Comment: Você trocou o atributo x.Cba_dt_abertura para DateTime na sua Entity? pois o erro fala que ele está tentando usar o método em uma string.

Comment: O atributo Cba_dt_abertura  da Entidade precisa ser DateTime, ja o Cba_dt_abertura  da sua model tem que ser string.

Comment: Fiz as alterações que você disse, porém me deu erro novamente, mas encontrei uma solução, o seu método está certo, deve ser algum erro aqui, obrigado pela ajuda, vou postar a solução que encontrei

Answer (score 1):

```
Cba_dt_abertura = DateTime.Parse(x.Cba_dt_abertura.ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

Comment: Bom, eu n consigo usar o "parse", mas fiz algo parecido que encontrei

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução alternativa na internet:

```
                var bancos = bdprincipalEntities.Contas_Bancarias.Select(
                    x => new {
                        Cba_codigo = x.Cba_codigo,
                        Cba_numero = x.Cba_numero,
                        Cba_tipo_conta = x.Cba_tipo_conta,
                        Cba_dt_abertura = x.Cba_dt_abertura,
                        Cba_gerente = x.Cba_gerente,
                        Emp_codigo = x.Emp_codigo,
                        Cba_situacao = x.Cba_situacao.Equals("A") ? "ATIVO" : "DESATIVADO"                           
                    }).ToList().Select(x => new
                    {
                        Cba_codigo = x.Cba_codigo,
                        Cba_numero = x.Cba_numero,
                        Cba_tipo_conta = x.Cba_tipo_conta,
                        Cba_dt_abertura = string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", x.Cba_dt_abertura),
                        Cba_gerente = x.Cba_gerente,
                        Emp_codigo = x.Emp_codigo,
                        Cba_situacao = x.Cba_situacao
                    });
```